# Python serial communication and run minicom command?

Tags: python, pi-4

Right now I am working on RPI 4, and connect UWB sensor to RPI through USB port

To run sensor, I need to type in terminal

```
minicom -D /dev/ttyAMC0
```

mincom will pop out. Then,

1. I need to press enter twice
2. type "nmt" and press enter
3. type enter twice
4. Then, type "lec" and enter to get data from sensor.

Is there way I can reduce this work into python code? So, I can just press run to get data from sensor.

I was able to get to the point where I type "minicom -D /dev/ttyAMC0" to open mincom connection through

```
os.system("minicom -D /dev/ttyAMC0")
```

However, I am looking for a way to run minicom command on python (command that I labels with number above).

I also tried

```
ser = Serial("/dev/ttyAMC0", 115200)
ser.write(b'\n\n')
ser.write(b'nmt')
ser.write(b'\n\n')
ser.write(b'lec')
```

But, it does not show anything.

Comment: https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shortintro.html

Comment: @goldilocks I also tried to connect serial port using ser = Serial(/dev/ttyACM0, 115200) and try to send command byte with ser.write(bytes("\n\n".encode()) however, I am getting no response. Is there something that did wrong?

Comment: You should edit those details into the question. We have a fairly strict format that new users accustomed to "discussion style" forums sometimes find awkward. Please take [the tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand better how the site works.

Comment: You can script minicom. It has been years since I did this but `man minicom` explains

Comment: Where does the sensor send the data?  If it is to the serial link you need to read the data.

Comment: @joan through USB port /dev/ttyACM0

Comment: So you need to read the data from the serial port.

Comment: Either script minicom OR write a complete program to run your task. You can't mix the two.